# How to remember God all the time?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhakti

How can one remember God/Vishnu/Krishna all the time, while simultaneously fulfilling his worldly duties.
Is there any thing written about it in the scriptures ?

Comment: Abhyasena tu Kaunteya